# Web3j how to get transaction status

Tags: transactions, ethereum, web3-java

I am using web3j to query the Ethereum blockchain. Now I want to check if a transaction was mined or just sent to the network. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: try this:   boolean sent = web3j.ethGetTransactionByHash(transactionReceipt.getTransactionHash()).send().getTransaction().isPresent();
  log.info("sent: {}", sent);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can consider using `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash [, callback])`.

It will return `null` for pending transactions and an object if the transaction is successful.

Comment: web3j v.s. web3.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/127298/web3-py-get-transaction

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * 通过hash查询交易状态，处理状态。成功success，失败fail，未知unknown
 * @param hash
 * @return
 */
public String txStatus(String hash){
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(hash)) {
        return STATUS_TX_UNKNOWN;
    }
    try {
        EthGetTransactionReceipt resp = web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(hash).send();
        if(resp.getTransactionReceipt().isPresent()) {
            TransactionReceipt receipt = resp.getTransactionReceipt().get();
            String status = StringUtils.equals(receipt.getStatus(), "0x1") ?
                    "success" : "fail";
            return status;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.info("txStatusFail {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return "hash_unknown";
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you can use `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash [, callback])`
It will return the object with *status*. It will be *false* for unsuccessful transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Use org.web3j.protocol.core.Ethereum ethGetTransactionReceipt function to get status using hash

```
public Boolean getTransactionStatus(Web3j web3j, String transactionHash) throws Exception{
                    
        Optional<TransactionReceipt> receipt = null;
        Boolean status=null;
                    
        try{ 
            receipt = web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(transactionHash).send().getTransactionReceipt();
            if(receipt.isPresent())
               status = receipt.get().isStatusOk();      
         }catch(IOException e){
            throw new Exception(e);
         }
         return status;
}
```